# SCOPE_IDENTITY() not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

When I try to get the last ID inserted on Database via SQL Server it returns __Page. Here is my code :

```
query = "INSERT INTO
             seekers(name, sname, lname, status, gender, dob, major, experince,
                     email, password, phone, valid, city)
             values (@name, @sname, @lname, @status ,@gender, @dob, @major,
                     @exp, @email, @password, @phone, 0, @city);
         SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";

// some code here related to parameters

command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
int id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Just read returned value without converting to `int` to see what you actually get from DB.

Answer (score 4):

If just you want to `SELECT` it use `OUTPUT`;

```
INSERT INTO seekers(name,sname,lname,status,gender,dob,major,experince,email,password,phone,valid,city)
OUTPUT INSERTED.IDENTITY_COL_NAME
values(@name,@sname,@lname,@status,@gender,@dob,@major,@exp,@email,@password,@phone,0,@city);
```

Answer (score 2):

As using `ExecuteScalar`. And ur first executing statement is `INSERT` so it returns number of records inserted.

To avoid this use `SET NOCOUNT ON` as shown below:

```
string Query = @"SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO table1(name) values('ttt');
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); SET NOCOUNT OFF;
";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a stored procedure like that;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [seekers_Insert]
 @ID uniqueidentifier OUTPUT,
 @name nvarchar(50) ,
  @sname nvarchar(50),

(other input parameters)
  AS
  INSERT INTO seekers(name,sname,lname,status,gender,dob,major,experince,email,
                         password,phone,valid,city)
                  values(@name,@sname,@lname,@status,@gender,@dob,@major,@exp,@email,
                         @password,@phone,0,@city)

   SET @ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    GO
```

and later you can take it

```
int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

we do this and works fine but we use return parameters for example in our stored procedure:

```
@RecordID int OUTPUT
```

... here the insert statement

```
SET @RecordID= SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

...

```
SELECT @RecordID
```